# How to generate series of numbers like 1, 501, 1001, 1501, 2001 then 2, 502, 1002, 1502, 2002; all the way to 2500

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'd like to generate series of numbers in following pattern, till 2500:

```
1
501
1001
1501
2001
2
502
1002
1502
2002
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

In the first cell, enter: `1`
In the second  cell, enter: `=A1+500` (Or wherever the first cell is located)
Copy the second cell three rows down, so that you have:
1
501
1001
1501
2001

Now just select them all, and drag it down to row 2500, and let autocomplete do its job.

[image]

Or, you could have a macro do the job for you, if you want.
Something like this:

```
Sub number()
Dim i As Long, oCN As Long, oColumn As String
oColumn = "A"

oCN = Columns(oColumn).Column
For i = 1 To 500
    Range(oColumn & Cells(Rows.Count, oCN).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Value = i
    Range(oColumn & Cells(Rows.Count, oCN).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Value = i + 500
    Range(oColumn & Cells(Rows.Count, oCN).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Value = i + 1000
    Range(oColumn & Cells(Rows.Count, oCN).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Value = i + 1500
    Range(oColumn & Cells(Rows.Count, oCN).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Value = i + 2000
Next i
End Sub
```

Here you can simply specify what column you want to have the list in, and it will start from row 2 (or lower if there's stuff in the column already).
So in this case, it would print in "`A2`" to "`A2501`".

You can use this in the visual basic editor in the developer tab, or just right click the tab and pick "show code".

Answer (score 0):

You can generate those values with this formula:

```
=500*MOD(ROW()-1,5)+INT((ROW()-1)/5)+1
```

The first two `1`s refer to the starting row.

Comment: This one successfully works at `Row 1`, downwards only,, so to use this Formula at any Row it should be improvised !!

Comment: When I said “The first two `1`s refer to the starting row.”, that meant that, if you wanted to start in row 42, you should change the formula to ```=500*MOD(ROW()-42,5)+INT((ROW()-42)/5)+1```.